# Application.Exit() and FormClosing event in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, formclosing

I have a single windows form application that is running in system tray icon.If the user press X button of the windows form a messagebox is displayed with Yes and No ( Yes ->close the form---No->keep the form running in system tray icon).
I was thinking to prevent the scenario when the user open another instance of the application when there is already an instance running so i have used this code :

```
 If Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName).Length> 1 Then 
 MessageBox.Show("Another instance is running", "Error Window", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Application.Exit()
End If
```

The problem is that when i want to test this the message is displayed but after i press ok, a new messagebox appears (that one from Private Sub Form_FormClosing ).If i choose NO i will have to instance running!
I have read that Application.Exit fires the Form_FormClosing event.

Is there any possibility to cancel the triggering of the Form_FormClosing event,or am i doing something wrong?

'this is the formclosing procedure

```
Private Sub Form_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Try
        Dim response As MsgBoxResult
        response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit", CType(MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, MsgBoxStyle), "Confirm")

        'If the user press Yes the application wil close
        'because the application remains in taskmanager after closing i decide to kill the current process
        If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()
        ElseIf response = MsgBoxResult.No Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
            Me.Hide()
            NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
        End If
```

PS: I am not a programmer so please don't be to harsh with me:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to Kill the current process or use the `End` Statement. If you have to use these then there is something amiss with your application.

When you want to end your application use `Me.Close`. This will fire the `FormClosing` event:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Select Case MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
            'nothing to do here the form is already closing
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
            e.Cancel = True 'cancel the form closing event
            'minimize to tray/hide etc here 
    End Select
End Sub
```

To stop more than one copy of your application from running use the option to [Make Single Instance Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328792/make-single-instance-application-what-does-this-do)

Comment: Thank for the answer...I have found the setting from Visual Studio Properties si it should be ok also to use this method...unfortunatelly i did not managed why my aplication doesn't shut down from task manager after closing...that it why i have find this temporary solution....Basically the application is a simple windows form.

Answer (score 1):

In the situation where you are just starting your application and are testing for previous instances I have used the [VB End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wt87xba.aspx) Statement to terminate the application.

> The End statement stops code execution abruptly, and does not invoke
>   the Dispose or Finalize method, or any other Visual Basic code. Object
>   references held by other programs are invalidated. If an End statement
>   is encountered within a Try or Catch block, control does not pass to
>   the corresponding Finally block.

```
If Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName).Length> 1 Then  
   MessageBox.Show("Another instance is running", "Error Window", MessageBoxButtons.OK,         MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) 
   End
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub main_master_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing 
If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
'Put you desired Code inside this! 
Msgbox("Application Closing from Taskbar") 
End If 
End Sub
```

It will Close the **exe** from **Taskbar** or kill Process. If user Close the
Application from **taskbar**.

```
CloseReason.UserClosing
```

event will close the **application** if it is closed by User from
**Taskber**