# How to prevent the running of rename application?

Tags: c#

With this code I can prevent a duplicate application from running the name given in the code .

But after the application is created, the name of that application (exe) can be changed and run multiple times in the same machine.

**How to prevent it from running?**

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "Demo";
            int ac = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Count();
            if (ac > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Application Already Running");
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to create a single-instance WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-wpf-application)

Comment: tldr; *system* (aka named) mutex or *system* (aka named) semaphore world well for this control between the same code running in different processes. It’s also sometimes an interview question :p

Comment: If you want Single Instance, follow above link. Do **not** Randomly kill Processes just because you want to be the only one named like that. Such behavior is between unwanted to Virus.

Comment: A list of known methods here: [Correct .NET way to implement a single instance application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14104988/7444103). My take, using a mix of mutex and UI Automation here: [Run the current application as Single Instance and show the previous instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555532/7444103)

Comment: [Single Instance Windows Form Application in C#](http://www.codescratcher.com/windows-forms/single-instance-windows-form-application-in-c/)