# Allow only one application instance

Tags: vb.net, single-instance

I'm sorry about my title may be it make you confusing (it's just I don't know what words should I use). My problem is I don't want to allow user to open my application multiple time. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not? This is a very annoying thing to do to a user.

Comment: @SLaks: It's not entirely unreasonable; ever try to open a second instance of Skype? Personally there are some cases where it would be _more_ annoying to get a new instance rather than be dropped into an existing one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the “Make single instance application” flag; in the solution explorer, right-click the project and select properties.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328792/make-single-instance-application-what-does-this-do) for more details.

MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8fz4ssw2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can u imagine that I'm using a code to check if the process is running to allow only one instance of my application :( just found this solution now, thanks, I feel stupid :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the “Make single instance application” flag; in the solution explorer

Comment: duplicate answer same as geoff